# Regex to match string with exact number of identifier characters

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Take the following paragraph:

```
#### And this will not work!
This is an *italic*... does it work!
This is a **bold** text and it will work!
Will this ***work***
```

I have built this regex `/(?:\*{2}.*?\*{2})/gm` to match words which start & end with `**` characters. However, my regex also matches the last line `Will this ***work***`, which I do not want it to.

How can I set a restriction to watch for the next character after the match not to be another `*`?

Thank you.

Comment: `/(?<!\*)\*{2}[^*]*\*{2}(?!\*)/g`? See https://regex101.com/r/UGJQxP/1

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, that did it for me. If you can post that as an answer, I will accept it. Cheers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should start posting your solutions as answers, as they are answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
string.match(/(?<!\*)\*{2}[^*]*\*{2}(?!\*)/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UGJQxP/1)

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is an asterisk immediately to the left of the current location
- `\*{2}` - double asterisk
- `[^*]*` - zero or more chars other than an asterisk
- `\*{2}` - double asterisk
- `(?!\*)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is an asterisk immediately to the right of the current location

JavaScript demo:

```js
const string = "#### And this will not work!\nThis is an *italic*... does it work!\nThis is a **bold** text and it will work!\nWill this ***work***";
console.log(string.match(/(?<!\*)\*{2}[^*]*\*{2}(?!\*)/g));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `[^\*]*` to match any number of characters that aren't an asterisk along with a negative look behind `(?<!\*)` which checks that the preceeding character isn't an asterisk and negative look ahead `(?!\*)` whcih checks that the following character isn't an asterisk:

```js
const str = `#### And this will not work!
This is an *italic*... does it work!
This is a **bold** text and it will work!
Will this ***work***`

console.log(str.match(/(?<!\*)\*{2}[^\*]*\*{2}(?!\*)/g))
```

Comment: @Kayote Because it is my solution copied from my comment, just `*` is escaped unnecessarily inside a character class.